# javascript function on button click works sometimes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Testing javascript on my asp.net page. I have a simple function that should display an image when button is clicked.  However, it works only if i add a second line with an Alert().  if i leave it out, clicking the button does not display the image.

```
   <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showIt() {
            document.getElementById("imgLoader").style.display = 'block';
//            alert("Message");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img ID="imgLoader" alt="Loading..." src="images/loader.gif" style="display:none" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="showIt();" />


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include your HTMLwhere you call this function so people can try to replicate the error

Comment: i added the rest of the page above.

Comment: Best way to find out what's wrong with JavaScript is always via the Developer's Console from the browser. Just set a breakpoint in the code and click on the button to see if it is running.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you might need a click event listener.  Here is a link on Javascript EventListener's.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: You should include example code and explain how it works, if that links breaks in the future and it happened to help, it would be no use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this part of code bellow!

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function function1()
{
alert("Message");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type='button' onclick='function1()' value='Click Me'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```